# Comparing Each Element of Two Lists in R

Tags: r, list, sapply

I have a dataset in R with the following structure:

```
data <- structure(list(Cust_ID = c("003", "023", "023", "023", "023", 
"041", "056", "056"), Record_Date = list(structure(16130, class = "Date"), 
    structure(c(16130, 16130, 16130, 16130), class = "Date"), 
    structure(c(16150, 16150, 16150, 16150), class = "Date"), 
    structure(c(16161, 16161, 16161, 16161), class = "Date"), 
    structure(c(16162, 16162, 16162, 16162), class = "Date"), 
    structure(16133, class = "Date"), structure(c(16088, 16088
    ), class = "Date"), structure(c(16095, 16095), class = "Date")), 
    Compare_Date = list(structure(16130, class = "Date"), structure(c(16130, 
    16150, 16161, 16162), class = "Date"), structure(c(16130, 
    16150, 16161, 16162), class = "Date"), structure(c(16130, 
    16150, 16161, 16162), class = "Date"), structure(c(16130, 
    16150, 16161, 16162), class = "Date"), structure(16133, class = "Date"), 
        structure(c(16088, 16095), class = "Date"), structure(c(16088, 
        16095), class = "Date"))), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Cust_ID", 
"Record_Date", "Compare_Date"))

  Cust_ID                Record_Date               Compare_Date
1     003                      16130                      16130
2     023 16130, 16130, 16130, 16130 16130, 16150, 16161, 16162
3     023 16150, 16150, 16150, 16150 16130, 16150, 16161, 16162
4     023 16161, 16161, 16161, 16161 16130, 16150, 16161, 16162
5     023 16162, 16162, 16162, 16162 16130, 16150, 16161, 16162
6     041                      16133                      16133
7     056               16088, 16088               16088, 16095
8     056               16095, 16095               16088, 16095
```

I would like to compare each element of "Record_Date" and each element of "Compare_Date."  I want the result to be equal to the amount of times the "Compare_Date" is within 14 days after the "Record_Date."  I know how to compare two vectors, but comparing two lists seems to be giving me trouble.  I have tried using lapply or sapply, but those can only loop through one list at a time.

Does anyone have an easy solution to this problem?  I would expect the expected output to look like the following:

```
   Within14
1:        0
2:        2
3:        1
4:        0
5:        1
6:        0
7:        0
8:        0
```

Comment: What would the expected result look like? How would the comparison be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, you are looking for `mapply`. You can edit the `FUN` argument of `mapply` to do what you want on each `RD` and `CD` argument.

`mapply` passes one element each of `data$Record_Date` and `data$Compare_Date` into `RD` and `CD` arguments of `FUN` respectively.

```
mapply(FUN = function(RD, CD) {
    d <- as.numeric(CD - RD)
    sum(d > 0 & d < 15)
}, RD = data$Record_Date, CD = data$Compare_Date)
## [1] 0 0 2 1 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: @Mike.Gahan If it's great, then you should checkmark it.

Comment: Sorry...somewhat of a newbie here.  All checked now